# Set property value of nullable datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, reflection, nullable

Try to update a specific property of my model with Reflection.
This works for all other types of my model except properties of type DateTime?

Code:

```
public void UpdateProperty(Guid topicGuid, string property, string value)
{
    var topic = Read(topicGuid);
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = topic.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    propertyInfo.SetValue(topic, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);

    topic.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

    Save();
}
```

The following error is thrown on the **Convert.ChangeType** part:

```
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
```

How can this be solved?

**Update**

Got it working with Daniel A. White 's solution

Code updated (probably needs some finetuning, but it works):

```
public void UpdateProperty(Guid topicGuid, string property, string value)
{
    var topic = Read(topicGuid);

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = topic.GetType().GetProperty(property);

    object changedType = propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?)
            ? DateTime.Parse(value)
            : Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType);

    propertyInfo.SetValue(topic, changedType, null);

    topic.DateModified = DateTime.Now;

    Save();
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'

Comment: you have to use `DateTime.Parse` or `TryParse` or related.

Comment: @DanielA.White Got it working with DateTime.Parse

Answer (score 16):

Try to replace

```
Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType)
```

by

```
Convert.ChangeType(value, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType)
```

(Not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert value to DateTime : 
DateTime.Parse(value);